# Check twitter status source / application name

Tags: oauth, twitter

I'm succesfully getting status messages by checking a user_timeline. I want to save the statuses in my database. I don't want to save the statuses that come from a specific registered application (e.g. Facebook, Tumblr).

I can only see if a message is coming from somewhere else by checking it's source attribute. Only the link the status message is reffering to is visible. I cannot see if the message is coming from the specific authenticated application or just a random facebook page because of the shortened urls.

Is there a normal way to see if status messages are coming from a registered application or do i just have to do a regex on the top-domain of the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source attribute only comes as HTML so you are either going to have to do a regex or match on the entire source HTML string.

Comment: I was afraid for that. I guess it's a thing Twitter should look into; it is an important attribute to identify a message.

Comment: It is a known issue with Twitter which I imagine will get fixed in v2 of the API. http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=75